# Importing data from excel to SAS

Tags: database, sas, export-to-excel, xlsx, import-from-excel

One interview question--I didn't get answer of this, please help me to solve this.

In excel file variable name having space in between (e.g- Shop Name), if we will bring excel data to the sas. How we will bring as it is, bcz in sas dataset, space is not allowed between the variable name?

Code:

```
proc import datafile='/home/roshnigupta16020/test (2).xlsx' out=testexcel dbms=xlsx replace; getnames=yes; run;
```

Comment: Did you try any code? What happened with the code you tried?

Comment: It depends on what the setting of the SAS option VALIDVARNAME is set to. https://documentation.sas.com/doc/en/pgmsascdc/9.4_3.5/acreldb/n0vnyuzncldjabn1923ug8svx7uh.htm

Comment: @Tom when i tried this code i got the answer.                                                              proc import datafile='/home/roshnigupta16020/test (2).xlsx'
out=testexcel
dbms=xlsx replace;
getnames=yes;
run;

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your PROC IMPORT syntax is good.

```
proc import datafile='/home/roshnigupta16020/test (2).xlsx' 
  out=testexcel dbms=xlsx replace
; 
  getnames=yes; 
run;
```

Depending on the setting of the VALIDVARNAME option PROC IMPORT will create different names for the variables.

With VALIDVARNAME=ANY the names will include the spaces.  Which means that to use the name in your SAS code you will need to use name literals, like `'Column 1'n`.

With other settings, like VALIDVARNAME=V7, then PROC IMPORT will replace invalid characters, like spaces, with underscores.  Then the name will not exactly match the column header in the spreadsheet.  But the name will be something like `Column_1` which is easier to include in your SAS code.

Comment: Thank you so much @Tom